# Name of villain in comic Doom Patrol

Tags: doom-patrol

I can remember in high school some twenty years ago, one of my classmates bought a collection of Doom Patrol. He showed it to me at a particular page and it was a villain doing a villain speech, ending with “Art for breakfast! Art for lunch! Art for tea!” Who was that villain and what was his story?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mr Nobody](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Eric_Morden_(New_Earth))

That particular scene is from [*Doom Patrol* vol 2 50](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Doom_Patrol_Vol_2_50)

Comment: Played brilliantly by the great Alan Tudyk in the TV series.